# Sample google ads not showing up in android (Mobile Ads SDK)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, admob

I am trying to add a banner ad in one of my fragments and I followed the exact steps mentioned in the documentation but for some reason, the ad does not show up.

onViewCreated method of the Fragment -

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    MobileAds.initialize(this.activity!!.applicationContext) {}

    val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
    adView.loadAd(adRequest)

    setUpRecyclerView()
}
```

XML -

```
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    ads:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    ads:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Manifest and gradle files have been updated as per the documentation.

If it helps, adding the following code to my fragment -

```
    override fun onDestroy() {
    adView.destroy()
    super.onDestroy()
}
```

throws this error -

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.destroy()' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, this was dumb, the ad was hiding behind the bottom navigation bar. I'll see if I can fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a fragment, so to get rid of the error call the "Fragment's onDestroy" method instead of onDestroy():

```
override fun onDestroyView() {
    adView.destroy()
    super.onDestroy()
}
```

In the other onDestroy your view has probably already been removed because the Fragment (and it's views) got destroyed

Comment: My bad, I fixed that thanks! The problem though is with the recycler view, somehow I can add ads above it but not below or on it, so the question changes to how can I add ads with recycler view.